# Stuck on closing socket while interposing JVM through LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, sockets

I am interposing JVM through LD_PRELOAD variable.

Basically, I want to build a virtual routing table (VRT). On bind() call, I modify the IP address and port parameters to my choice (which I save in VRT). Also, I add the socket descriptor (first argument to bind()) to a link list. (Till this stage, socket has a sin_family type of AF_INET6).

Now when the socket is closed (close()), I want to delete the virtual routing table entry. So, I check to see if the socket descriptor we are trying to close is stored in the link list. If it is, it means that its records exists in VRT, so I should delete the VRT entry before closing the socket. The problem I am facing is that at this stage, the same socket descriptor has a sin_family value of 1 (I don't know what does it stand for) instead of 10 (AF_INET6, value during bind()). Moreover, I tried printing IP address and port of the socket descriptor at this stage but it was garbage.

I do not know what I am missing.

UPDATE:
There is no problem with my code. The anomaly is appearing because of the following behavior of JVM (which I traced through strace)

```
9722  socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 12
...(receive messages)...
9722  dup2(11, 12)                      = 12 (?!?)
9722  close(12)                         = 0
```

JVM duplicates another file descriptor over our socket, due to which its sin_family is not displayed properly on close(). Strange!

Comment: @AhmedJolani cool down buddy ..., it's a good idea to stay polite, mostly this helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did hook into `shutdown()` also?

Comment: @alk the question is so ambiguous that's all.

Comment: So you need to hook into `dup*()` also.

Comment: What does the trace tell about where the file descriptor 11 comes from?

Comment: And also pretty much anything else which may modify the fd (fcntl anyone?) :)

Answer (score 0):

`sin_family == 1` is `AF_UNIX`, that is pipes or domain name sockets.

---

Are you sure it is really the "same" socket descriptor? How do you identify it though? It's integer value is unique to a process only.

If the process your are `LD_PRELOAD`ing forks off children they will be using your hooks too using the same set of descriptors as the parent and all their siblings and children will do.

So to solve this ambiguity get the PID using `getpid()` in the hooking `bind()` code and add the PID to the key your storing for this socket.

---

`dup2(int fdOld, int fdNew)` closes `fdNew` prior to makeing it a copy of `fdOld`. But you can not hook the call to `close()` it does, I suppose :-(.

Comment: Currently I am using a simple Java program that does not forks children.